# Excel - change list of values into a 'sequence' with count

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of data which I need to reduce into a 'sequential list', with a count of data returned.
Perhaps an easy explanation is to show:
[Example of the list - and the 'reduced sequence'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUr7y.png)

In short: the entry '415' appears twice, followed by '242' three times, then '417' then '415' etc.
That needs to be reduced to '415 - 2', '242 - 3', '417 - 1, '415 - 1' etc (as seem in the image).

I have used 'match' to mark where there are changes in the sequence. But I need a way to 'tell me how many entries are between the changes' if that makes sense. The data changes on a monthly basis, so this needs to be automated in some fashion.
I've been pulling my hair for several days, and I'm ready to farm this out for assistance!

Answer (score 1):

With UNIQUE and COUNTIFS:

```
LET(
    R,A:A
    RNG,FILTER(R,R<>""),
    UNQ,UNIQUE(RNG),
    CNT,COUNTIFS(R,UNQ),
    HSTACK(UNG,CNT)
   )
```

This will create a unique list from all values in column A that are not blank.  Then use COUNTIF to count the number of times it is found in column A and return the results side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Details depend on Excel version.
My proposal requires a helper column.
Helper and Sequence columns contain individual formulas.
Frequency column (`D` or `F`) is a multicell array formula (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`) in older versions or dynamic formula in new versions (365 and 2021). SEQUENCE function (col. `F`) is available in new versions.
[image: sequence]

Answer (score 0):

Just for information: there is a method without formulas - in case you are not yet fluent in built-in functions, but are familiar with standard Excel operations.

Enable macro recording.
Go to the column with your values (for example, cell A1). Select [**Subtotals**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a) on the Data tab, choose Count instead of Sum, click OK.
At the top left, click the button with the number 2 to hide unnecessary details.

[image: Hide details]

Press Ctrl+* to select the entire range. Now press [**F5 – Select – Visible Cells Only and copy the range to the clipboard**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-visible-cells-only-6e3a1f01-2884-4332-b262-8b814412847e).
Select the target cell and use [**Paste Special-Values**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-and-paste-specific-cell-contents-a956b1c3-cd5a-4245-852c-42e8f83ffe71).
Go back to cell A1 and delete the subtotals and the extra column.
Remove supporting texts from the results table (for example, using Data-Text by Columns).
Stop recording the macro. You'll end up with code like this:

```
Sub createSeq()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlCount, TotalList:=Array(1), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Selection.RemoveSubtotal
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range("A3").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("E1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 9)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Every month after changing the data, run this macro and get the result.

Of course, **methods with formulas are preferable**. It’s just that for any problem there are several solutions - your task is to choose the acceptable one.